# awk command to split nth field

Tags: awk, gawk

I am learning AWK and was trying some exercises on built-in string functions.

Here's my exercise:

I have a file containing as below

```
RecordType:83    
1,2,3,a|x|y|z,4,5
```

And my desired output is as below:

```
RecordType:83       
1,2,3,a,4,5         
1,0,0,x,4,5         
1,0,0,y,4,5       
1,0,0,z,4,5
```

I wrote an awk command for the above output.

```
awk -F',' '$1 ~ /RecordType:83/{print $0}

$1 == 1{

split($4,splt,"|")

for(i in splt)

{ 

if(i==1) 

print $1,$2,$3,splt[i],$5,$6 

else 

print $1,0,0,splt[i],$5,$6

} 

}' OFS=, file_name
```

The above command looks so clumsy. Is there any way minimizing the command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest possible one-liner I could manage:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{n=split($4,a,"|");for(;i++<n;){$4=a[i];print;$2=$3=0}}NR==1' OFS=, file
RecordType:83    
1,2,3,a,4,5
1,0,0,x,4,5
1,0,0,y,4,5
1,0,0,z,4,5
```

The much more readable script *(recommended)*:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","                                       # Comma delimiter 
}
NR==1 {                                              # If the first line in file
    print $0                                         # Print the whole line
    next                                             # Skip to next line
}
{
    n=split($4,a,"|")                                # Split field four on |
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                                # For each sub-field
        print $1,i==1?$2OFS$3:"0"OFS"0",a[i],$5,$6   # Print the output
}
```

Comment: awk -F, 'NR>1{split($4,a,"|");for(i in a) $4=a[i];print;$2=$3=0}}NR==1' OFS=, file

Comment: You are better off using a traditional for loop so order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

another shorter one-liner

```
 awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{n=split($4,a,"|");while(++i<=n){$4=a[i];print;$2=$3=0}}NR==1' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{n=split($4,a,"|");while(++i<=n){$4=a[i];print;$2=$3=0}}NR==1' file                                                                          
RecordType:83    
1,2,3,a,4,5
1,0,0,x,4,5
1,0,0,y,4,5
1,0,0,z,4,5
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the better answer but if we think at the next level. This command works only for a single comma delimited line.

Comment: Adding to the above comment I think we need to change the loop count

Comment: @kattashri if you have more comma separated lines, you have to reset the `i` after loop. it looks `awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{n=split($4,a,"|");while(++i<=n){$4=a[i];print;$2=$3=0;}i=0}NR==1' file` your `for(i in a)` is not safe. because `i in a` doesn't guarantee the order.