# How to split the values of the particular column from the csv file using unix command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Data I have

```
item     ids
358159   419463_I,528691_I,618536_I,768347_I,794716_I,802503_I,850094_I

358944   090169_I,398844_I,698490_I
```

Result I need

```
item      ids
358159   419463_I
358159   528691_I
358159   618536_I
358159   768347_I
358159   794716_I
358159   802503_I
358159   850094_I
358944   090169_I
358944   398844_I
```

Can this be formatted using unix commands awk or sed

Comment: Yes, not too difficult. Start [at the awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) to learn how to use [tag:awk].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk command to split nth field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886428/awk-command-to-split-nth-field)

Comment: Your case is simpler than the one in that question; should be easy for you to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F[," "] 'NR==1 { printf "%s\t%s\n","itm","ids" } NR>1 { itm=$1;for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) { if ($NF!=" ") { print itm" "$i } } }' file
```

Using awk, set the field delimiter to space or comma. When the first record is encountered, print the headers, otherwise, loop through the fields, taking a note of the first field (itm) and printing itm along with the field on separate lines.